# Button on form looks like it is being constantly pressed after being clicked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in Access 2013 that uses a button to jump to another form.
However when the button is clicked certain requirements have to be met in order for the jump process to actually be executed. If the requirements are not met the user is forced to stay on the current form (with the button).

When this happens the button stays in the clicked (i.e. pressed down) state on the form, making it look like it's being constantly pressed.
(Note: If the button is clicked again and the requirements again aren't met it pops back out...)

[image: Button in unclicked state (left), and button that stays in clicked state (right)]

Is there any way to change the appearance of the button back to the unclicked appearance after every click when the user is forced to stay on the current form?

Many thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: That's an odd behavior for a button. Are you sure you didn't use a toggle button by accident? If yes, please provide the `_Click()` event procedure code (a minimal example that shows the behavior).

Comment: Haha. You're right. Turns out it is a toggle button! 
Thanks for your help! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular button can stay depressed for a short while, while its `_Click()` event procedure is running.

But once that finishes, it always returns to its normal state.

So the assumption was, that a **toggle button** was used instead, which turned out to be correct.